# sticky uitableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sticky

i'm having a problem with uitableview when i scroll it up and down many times it becomes sticky and all the containing view becomes sticky too.

here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"         %@",
                            [SongsNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UIImageView *b=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 34)];
    b.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbuttone.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:b];
    [b release];
    UIButton *b2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 0, 50, 35)];
    [b2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buye.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:b2];
    [b2 release];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
}
```

after update:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"         %@",[SongsNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:b];
       // [b release];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:b2];
        //[b2 release];

        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
```

and in the viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

b=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 34)];
b.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbuttone.png"];

b2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 0, 50, 35)];
[b2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buye.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reloading your images for each call of that function. When scrolling this function gets called really a lot of times which is not neccessary, in particular because your images are static and identical for each cell.

Load the two images once when the view did load, save a reference in the view controller and reuse them. When the table view requests the cell. This very likely will solve your problem.

Comment: thnx so much for replying
as i understood i loaded them in the viewdidload and editted the code to:

[cell.contentView addSubview:b];
// [b release];
[cell.contentView addSubview:b2];
//[b2 release];

that made the 2 pics only in one cell

Comment: @MH, what did you load in the viewDidLoad method, just the images, or the image view and the button? You should maybe edit your post, so we can see what you have now.

Comment: @MH you should save and reuse the UIImage only, not the UIImageView. (Your image view can not be reused like this, which means it can be displayed only once. That's why you see it in one cell only.) You can optimize your code further by including the UIImageView through the Interface Builder. Then it is part of the Prototype Cell and does not need to be instantiated for each call. But you'd need to subclass UITableViewCell and provide a link via properties to those image views to set them programmatically.

Comment: thnx alot guys i learned about the custom cell as u recommended and now everything works fine...thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

ok for anyone who will get that confusing problem stop adding uicontrols to ur uitableviewcell and use custom cell like in this tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwcBdCUZNWs